# mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a method for inserting something in the db

I read about the problem but it seems like it's appearing only when people try to SELECT something and don't fetch the result.

the error I get is Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

```
class Connection
{
    private $host = NULL;
    private $user = NULL;
    private $password = NULL;
    private $database = NULL;
    private $link = NULL;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database)
    {
        $this -> host = $host;
        $this -> user = $user;
        $this -> password = $password;
        $this -> database = $database;
        $this -> link = new mysqli($this -> host, $this -> user, $this -> password, $this -> database) or die;
        $this -> link -> set_charset("utf8") or die;
    }

    // ex. Insert("mail", "`name`, `content`", "'john', 'lorem'")
    public function Insert($dbname,$columns,$values)
    {
        if($dbname && $columns && $values)
        {
        $this -> link -> query("INSERT INTO" . $dbname . " (" . $columns . ") VALUES (" . $values . ")") or die($this -> link);
        }
    }
}


$connection = new Connection(host,user,password,database);

$brand = (isset($_POST['brand'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['brand']) : NULL;
$horsepower = (isset($_POST['horsepower'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['horsepower']) : NULL;
$manufacturedate = (isset($_POST['manufacturedate'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['manufacturedate']) : NULL;
$importer = (isset($_POST['importer'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['importer']) : NULL;
$description = (isset($_POST['description'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['description']) : NULL;
if( !empty($brand) && 
    !empty($horsepower) &&
    !empty($manufacturedate) &&
    !empty($importer) &&
    !empty($description)
    ){
    $connection -> Insert(
        "cars",
        "`brand`, `manufacturedate`, `horsepower`, `importer`, `description`",
        "'". $brand . "', '" . $manufacturedate . "', '" . $horsepower . "', '" . $importer . "', '" . $description . "'");
}
```

Comment: On what line this error throws?

Comment: in the function Insert in the class Connection the row starting with 
$this -> link -> query

Comment: `$this->link` in `die` is object. It can't be converted to string

Comment: I hope that doesn't sound rude but may I ask for the proper way to view the correct error?

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: Bless you and the people who help people like me. If someone is interested the problem was there is no space between INSERT INTO and the name of the database. The error was "table X does not exist".